# Porque hibernate crea las columnas de manera desordenada?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

estoy trabajando con esta clase usuario

@Data

@AllArgsConstructor

@NoArgsConstructor

@Builder

@Entity

@Table(name = "users")

public class UserEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String firstName;

@NotBlank
private String lastName;

@Size(max = 10)
private String phone;

@Email
@NotBlank
@Size(max = 80)
private String email;

@NotBlank
private String password;

private LocalDate dateCreated;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = RoleEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id"))
private Set<RoleEntity> roles;
```

}

al momento de ejecutar hibernate crea la tabla de esta forma

**Hibernate: create table users (date_created date, id bigint not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), password varchar(255), phone varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB**

alguien tiene alguna idea de xq lo genera de esa forma ?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El orden de los factores en un tabla, no afecta absolutamente en nada...